# Change monolog channel in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, monolog

As stated here you can't change channel on monolog instance https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/issues/224

As Laravel docs says for additional mnolog configuration the most you have is monolog instance you can get with `$app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) {...})` or `$monolog = Log::getMonolog();`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors

I am logging to database with eloquent handler, and I want to be able to have separate logs by using `->where('channel', 'my_channel1')`.

Then how to set channel for Log:: facade on application start?

Comment: I believe you're trying to achieve setting a custom log path for your channel? For that, see [this solution](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/advance-logging-with-laravel-and-monolog)

Comment: I edited post, I am logging to database using this reader/handler https://github.com/stevebauman/log-reader